# Google app script to create and sort variables dynamically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am wondering if there's a a way to have Google app scripts sort data before writing it to cells.
Here's the very basic script I'm working from. It compares my current inventory to a pre-set restock point listed in another cell.

```
// r = Row Number
for (var r = 3; r <= 196; r++) {
  var currentInventory = sheet.getRange(r, 98 + c).getValue();
  var restockLevel = sheet.getRange(r, 197 + c).getValue();
  if (currentInventory < restockLevel) {
    var color = sheet.getRange(r, 3).getValue();
    sheet.getRange(r, 9).setValue(color);
    sheet.getRange(r, 10).setValue(restockLevel - currentInventory);
  } // End IF
} // End LOOP
```

This will of course create a list in column 10 of all the instances where my current inventory is less than my restock point, with associated colors in col 9, however there will be blank cells whenever current inventory is greater than the restock point. I'm trying to figure out a way to do the comparison and then sort the data before writing to the cells.

Not included in this script, I will want to repeat this compare-and-sort process appending to columns 9 & 10.

My initial thoughts are to have the scripts create a variable and assign the value only if current inventory < restock point, then sort those variables, then write to cells. I'm not sure how (or if) GAS can create variables dynamically.

I am very new to Google app scripts, so I apologize if this is a very simple answer. I've tried looking online and in script tutorials but haven't found anything so far. Thanks in advance for the help! I'm learning all I can!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with no undefined variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to compare difference value from different column, it will be faster to write all value into `array` and perform comparison, after that `array.sort()` function can be used to rearrange the number before write to new column, here is code that you may find it useful:

```
function newStocl(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var currentStk = sheet.getRange("A2:A9").getValues();
  var reStk = sheet.getRange("B2:B9").getValues();
  var newBal = [];

  for (var i = 0; i< currentStk.length;i++){
    if (currentStk[i][0] < reStk[i][0]){
      var j = 0;
      newVal = reStk[i][0] - currentStk[i][0];
      newBal.push(newVal);
    }
  }
  newBal.sort(function(a, b){return b-a});

 //From this part is to convert 1d array to 2d, contribution by Yuri using Javascript EM6
 var arrNewBal = newBal.map(x =>[x]);  
 
  sheet.getRange(2,3,arrNewBal.length,1).setValues(arrNewBal);
}
```

The sample sheet, where you can amend it so that it can compare column from different sheet:

[image]

Comment: your second loop look a bit verbose. You can change its to: `for (var x = 0; x < newBal.length; x++) { arrNewBal.push( [newBal[x]] )  }` or even better: use `map` instead of the loop: `var arrNewBal = newBal.map(x => [x])`. Just in case.

Comment: @YuriKhristich, ok, let me do some testing, as I only have basic skill in Javascript, will appreciate can apply EM6 in the looping :)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys - I will play around with these ideas and when I find the one that works best I'll post it here.

Comment: What is var j = 0 for? I don't see j appearing in any part of the script.

Comment: My mistake, when I try to solve the problem, I used as part of the looping testing, but at the end it`(var j = 0)` can be deleted and still work without no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if understand the problem correctly. I don't see your input and desired output data, and I'm a bit lazy to guess it from your code. )

So, just in case, Google Spreadsheet has the inner function to sort a range. Just select your range and column for sorting and here we go:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1:B5').sort(1);
```

It will sort cells A1:B5 (by its first column).

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sortsortspecobj